# How can I convert a series of keys to locations with a Pandas index?

Tags: pandas

I am trying to use a Pandas `Index` manually to facilitate bidirectional lookups between key values and positions.

Suppose I have an index:

```
index = pd.Index(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
```

If I want to convert positions to indices, that is easy:

```
index[pd.Series([0,3,2,0,0,1])
```

yields `'a', 'd', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'b'`.

However, I cannot find a way to do the other direction in bulk: given a series of keys, how do I determine their positions?

```
index.???[pd.Series(['b', 'c', 'a'])]
```

I want `1, 2, 0`. I can do this for individual elemnts with `get_loc`, but that function is not vectorized.

Pandas seems to do this under the hood — how else would `.loc` lookups work? — but I cannot find an exposed method to do this from Python code.  If it's exposed in Cython somehow, that would be acceptable; my use case is preparing arrays to pass off to Cython routines for optimized computation.

Comment: The best I could do is the following:  `pd.Series(np.arange(len(index)),index=index).loc[['b','c','a']].values`

Comment: @ScottBoston Yep, that's my workaround too, and it feels like there really should be a more direct (and more space-efficient) way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Index.get_indexer`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_indexer.html) method is the key. Pandas seems to call position-based selectors 'indexers'; the `get_indexer()` method gets such an indexer given an array of values.

```
>>>> index.get_indexer(pd.Series(['b', 'c', 'a']))
array([1, 2, 0], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: I found this by code-diving through the Pandas source, and figuring out how `loc` was implemented.